# Почему не подгружаются css?

Tags: html, css

На одной странице сайта не подгружаются css стили, не могу понять почему.

`http://www.vilnatribuna.com.ua/mariupol/catalog/create-new-item.html` - сама страница

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://www.vilnatribuna.com.ua/components/com_sobi2/includes/com_sobi2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

А это css стиль в хедере тот, который нужен и который не подгружается.

Почему?

Comment: Ужас... За это и не перевариваю Joomla, никакой последовательности в исходном коде страницы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подгружается всё нормально, другой вопрос, что не применяются стили. Меня оч. смущают абсолютные пути, не знаю почему.

[image]

UPD. Нашел:

```
span#sobi2Details_field_description {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px; /* position it vertically */


/* Styles for the labels of the fields */
/* Add style for each field you added in the form span#sobi2Listing_field_yourname_label */
span#sobi2Listing_field_street_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_postcode_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_county_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_country_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_email_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_contact_person_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_phone_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_fax_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_city_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_hotline_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_phone_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_federal_state_label,
span#sobi2Listing_field_website_label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но взгляните еще раз) я с двух компов со всех браузеров пересмотрел - результат один - данные css не прогружаются, а именно они отвечают за то, что в самом центре (форма добавления компании):

http://i.imgur.com/GRVAm.png - вот так должно быть (это на Денвере набросал), таблица с рамкой, кнопки Отменить,Отправить - справа....

http://i.imgur.com/7aWgN.png - а здесь стили не применяются (на сайте), таблица без рамки и заданных размеров, кнопки влево улетели.

Неужели у всех как на первом рисунке? Else { вопрос остается в силе };

Comment: Загружатся, загружаются, но почему-то не применяются.

Comment: :D Так и знал, у вас в самом файле ошибка. Обновил ответ.

Comment: ДА, да, спасибо Вам за всё!!!) Всем спасибо за ответы!
зы: Не понял про какой ответ речь, поясните пожалуйста и как его закрыть.
ззы: что это у Вас за софт, который на скрине выше?

Comment: Ой, сори, вопрос закрывайте. Нужно выбрать понравившийся ответ и нажать слева от него кружочек с галочкой.
Софт называется Chrome (Гугл хром), еще удобен для отладки firefox с плагином firebug. Если занимаетесь разработкой сайтов, это незаменимый софт.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перегрузить через Ctrl+F5 и отключить баннерорезку. 
У меня все чудесно грузит

Comment: аналогично - никаких проблем не обнаружено...

Answer (score 0):

Ты проверь права на файлы, поставь 777 или 775, стили часто из за недостатка прав не подгружаются)

Comment: поставил 777 на всю папку с компонентом - нифига(

Comment: я тебе могу сказать чувак что я открыл страницу и файлик успешно подгружен

Comment: точняк, раз стиль не применяется то ошибка в файле самом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить в HEAD com_sobi2.css в самый конец, чтобы он последним подгружался.

Comment: Открыл в Opera исходный код, поставил строку com_sobi2.css в самый конец, нажал "Применить изменения" - ничего не произошло. 

Или имеешь ввиду чтобы страница генерировалась с этой строкой внизу изначально?